# javascript form won't submit() from escape key captured with addEventListener

Tags: javascript, forms, submit

**UPDATE** -  I added the following link to the html form. When clicked, form.submit() works as it should.

```
<a href="#" onClick="post_to_url('abc');">click</a>
```

form.submit() only doesn't work when capturing a keypress.

**Update 2** - I changed event.keyCode == 27 to event.keyCode == 65 and voila, with the press of the 'A' key, the submit() will work. So the problem is with some interference with the escape key. Any ideas?

**UPDATE 3 - solved** - THE SOLUTION is to change keydown to keyup in the code below

**End Update**

My goal is to capture a user escape keypress and go to a new url. I have successfully captured the escape key and called the function which creates a form on the fly to submit with the passed url. I have verified the url has been passed correctly with an alert(), but the form won't submit. I can't figure out what isn't working. Thanks in advance.

The key handler which captures the escape key is here (NOTE: THE SOLUTION is to change keydown to keyup in the code below- I left it alone for the integrity of the post) :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
    // Bind to both command (for Mac) and control (for Win/Linux)
    if (event.keyCode == 27) {          
    if (document.getElementById('url')){
        path = document.getElementById('url').value;
        post_to_url(path);
    }
    }
}, false);
</script>
```

The function to create the form to post is here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function post_to_url(path, params, method) {
method = method || "post"; // Set method to post by default if not specified.
// The rest of this code assumes you are not using a library.
// It can be made less wordy if you use one.
var form = document.createElement("form");
form.setAttribute("method", method);
form.setAttribute("action", path);
for(var key in params) {
    if(params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
        hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
        hiddenField.setAttribute("name", key);
        hiddenField.setAttribute("value", params[key]);

        form.appendChild(hiddenField);
     }
}

document.body.appendChild(form);
form.submit();
}
</script>
```

I'm including the HTML code to make this example complete:

```
<body>
    <form id = 'close' action='' method="POST">
        <input id="url" type="text" value="urlHere">
        <input type="submit" name="OK">
        <!--when clicking on this - form.submit() works as it should -->
        <a href="#" onClick="post_to_url('abc');">click</a>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: I'm going to step out on an untested limb here -- but try `form.method` and `form.action` instead.  In the DOM, attributes and properties are quite different things.

Comment: I tried form.method = method; form.action = path; but this didn't help. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Your code works fine but i think you are testing on ie and it requires some modification in current code

Comment: Good thought, but I'm on Firefox 22.0 (tested in IE as well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I changed "keydown" to "keyup". So simple - took me hours. The final listener code follows. For my needs, I didn't pass any parameters to post_to_url() except the url path. You will likely want to pass parameters. You can see Moje's example above.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
    // Bind to both command (for Mac) and control (for Win/Linux)
    if (event.keyCode == 27) {          
    if (document.getElementById('url')){
        path = document.getElementById('url').value;
        post_to_url(path);
    }
    }
}, false);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you are passing the `params` argument when you call `post_to_url`. This doesnt seem to happen inside your keydown event handler
Second check that the value of `document.getElementById('url').value` points to a script that you want your data submitted to.
Third, make sure the `params` argument is a js Object with members/keys. 
**N.B.**You do not need to add the form to the document in order to submit.
**EDIT** After going thru the above checklist, you should have the following code that works.....

```
var prm = {"ABC":"123"}//object to be submitted

function post_to_url(path, params, method) {
    method = method || "post"; // Set method to post by default if not specified.
    // The rest of this code assumes you are not using a library.
    // It can be made less wordy if you use one.
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.setAttribute("method", method);
    form.setAttribute("action", path);
    for(var key in params) 
        if(params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("name", key);
            hiddenField.setAttribute("value", params[key]);
            form.appendChild(hiddenField);
         }
    form.submit();
}

window.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
    // Bind to both command (for Mac) and control (for Win/Linux)
    if (event.keyCode == 27) {          
        post_to_url("index.php",prm);//swap index.php with your url, for prm, see above
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: I don't need any params since everything is contained in the path. But just to test, I passed {'q':'a'} in the function call. The url is a valid page on my server (and I've verified it is getting passed), but the form never gets submitted. Any other thoughts? I've added the only HTML in my test form and so the whole test is above

Comment: I pasted this code and it didn't work. With the addition of <a href="#" onClick="post_to_url('abc');">click</a> the submit() will work if I click on this link and if I also add back the line of code: document.body.appendChild(form); Can I presume you tested this and it works on your machine?

Comment: Getting closer! I changed event.keyCode == 27 to event.keyCode == 65 as a test. Now press the letter 'A' and it works! So there is something about the escape key that is interfering. FYI - document.body.appendChild(form) is needed for it to work. Now to figure out what is interfering with the escape key.